# Grep number from filename with special character

Tags: regex, perl

I have a filename contain a lot of '_' and i want to take the number between _. Below is my code try to get the number.

```
$file=~ m|\s+/b_(\d+)/.*|;
my $number=$1;  
print " $number\n";
```

My $file is like a_0_b_1_c2.txt. and i want to get the number 1 from the filename. What wrong is my code. Thanks

Comment: only the number 1?

Comment: `m/\_(\d+)\_([^\_]*)$/g` just try this

Comment: Just for reference: your regex matches a string that
1) starts with one or more whitespaces, followed by
2) a `/`, 
3) a `b`,
4) an `_`,
5) one or more digits,
6) a `/`,
7) some (including none) arbitrary characters.
For example, the string ` /b_123/` would match but you don't have any leading whitespace nor slashes in your input.

Comment: You are confusing the delimiters. Either `$v =~ m|...|` OR `$v =~ /.../`

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the unrelevant part of your regex, use:

```
$file =~ m|b_(\d+)|;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the lines:

```
my ($number) = $file =~ /b_(\d+)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex Reference for further understandings [1](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

```
my $str = "a_0_b_1_c2.txt";

print "", ($str=~m/\_(\d+)\_([^\_]*)$/g)[0];
```